# How to remove / set line breaks (soft returns) in R flextable (merged cells)

Tags: r, flextable

I am trying to properly set line breaks in `flextable` formatted tibble.

```
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)

tibble(Ind1 = rep("Indicator name 1", 3), 
       ranges1 = c("[0; 1)", "[1; 2)", "[2; 3)"), 
       `[0; 1.5)` = c("Text11\na\nb\nc\nd\ne", "Text21\na\nb\nc\nd\ne", "Text31\na\nb\nc\nd\ne"),
       `[1,5; 3)` = c("Text12\na\nb\nc\nd\ne", "Text22\na\nb\nc\nd\ne", "Text32\na\nb\nc\nd\ne"),
       `[3; 4.5)` = c("Text13\na\nb\nc\nd\ne", "Text23\na\nb\nc\nd\ne", "Text33\na\nb\nc\nd\ne")) %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  flextable::theme_box() %>% 
  flextable::bold(j = c(1, 2)) %>%
  flextable::rotate(j = c(1, 2), rotation = "btlr") %>% 
  merge_v(j = 1) %>% 
  flextable::add_header_row(colwidths = c(1, 1, 3),
                            values = c("", "", "Indicator name\n2"))
```

I got stuck as I am getting this wrong output:

[image]

The line breaks are automatically set breaking the line at unnecessary positions (red arrows).

What is the proper way to stretch the rotated text to the extent of merged cells and how to remove text from header with merging four upper left corner cells (yellow box) if I want to get the following output?

[image]

**Appended**

Emptying the yellow square at header and merging its cells
can be solved by:

```
%>% mk_par(i = 2, j = c(1, 2), value = as_paragraph(""), part = "header") %>% 
  merge_at(i = c(1, 2), j = c(1, 2), part = "header")
```

Comment: Are you viewing the HTML table in rstudio viewer or in a classical browser? I can see that effect but only in rstudio viewer, it works as expected with FF, chrome or edge

Comment: @DavidGohel Sorry for the late reply. I was not ready to answer you as I was seeking for any regularity of the output. Unfortunately I did not find any. Primary I took the screenshot from RStudio viewer where it was placed in an unproper place. Lateron I found that rasterization of table output with sending by plumber to front-end gave me partially proper label output. However intendation of paragraps was broken (some irregular paragraps were printed intended, others - not). I'll try either sending html to front-end instead of sending a base64 png, or knit an rmarkdown docx.

Comment: open an issue on github and we will see how to help.